# Howto add an existing VS project to Mercurial (using TortoiseHG or VirtualHG)

Tags: visual-studio-2010, mercurial, tortoisehg

I am new to Mercurial / TortoiseHG / VirtualHG. After reading some tutorials I still fail to understand how it is supposed to work.

Could someone please explain in a few simple steps how I add an existing VS2010 project to Mercurial using TortoiseHG or VirtualHG, and how I go from there?

So after adding it to Mercurial, what do I need to do to start working on this project again? Years ago I have worked with Visual SourceSafe, so maybe this experience confuses me right now.

Also I'd like to know what to do when colleagues want to work on this project.

Comment: Was one of the tutorials you read [this one](http://hginit.com/01.html) at [hginit.com](http://hginit.com)?

Comment: @JoelBFant Yes I did and things are a lot clearer by now. It's just "hg init" (in the project folder I want to add to Mecurial source control), "hg add" and "hg commit", of equivalent commands via TortoiseHG. Setting up a server is a lot trickier however.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see in the comments that you managed to get your source files under version control with:

```
$ hg init
# (setup .hgignore)
$ hg add
$ hg commit
```

Great! To share the project with your colleguages you need to make the repository accessible  to them somehow. You have three options:

- **Filesystem access:** This is the easiest if you already have a shared network drive setup. You put the repository on the shared drive where everybody can read and write. People make a clone from the drive back to their own machine and work on the files there. They commit there as well and finally use `hg push` to send their changes back to the repository on the shared drive.

  Make sure that everybody uses *version 2.0 or later* with such a setup! There has been bugs in earlier versions of Mercurial that could cause repository corruption when pushing to a repository on a network drive.
- **HTTP server:** You can use `hg serve` to start a built-in webserver in Mercurial. The server can be used to clone from. In a trusted environment you can start it as

  ```
  $ hg serve --config "web.push_ssl=no" --config "web.allow_push=*"
  ```

  to disable the default security settings and allow anybody to push new changes to the server.

  For more heavy-duty use, we recommend setting up a "real" webserver and install the `hgweb` (Fast)CGI script that comes with Mercurial. See the [Mercurial wiki](http://mercurial.selenic.com/wiki/PublishingRepositories) for information on that.
- **SSH server:** This is easy if you have an existing Unix setup where people have SSH login to a central server. You need to install Mercurial on the server and create a repository there that people have read and write access to. This is also [covered in the wiki](http://mercurial.selenic.com/wiki/SharedSSH).